# Project specific ghci init file permission warnings

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

With ghc 8.0.2 if I create a .ghci file mode 644 in my project directory on starting ghci this warning is issued:

```
*** WARNING: .ghci is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
Suggested fix: execute 'chmod go-w .ghci'
```

On adopting this suggestion, when starting ghci we then get:

```
*** WARNING: . is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
Suggested fix: execute 'chmod go-w .'
```

Adopting this suggestion makes the warnings go away. That's well and good, but this is tedious and annoying, especially since using stack the directory permissions created by default are not what ghci appears to want.

Why does adding a .ghci file cause this behaviour, and what is it exactly that ghci is worried about? Without a local directory .ghci file ghci does not protest about permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I now find this is an issue that has been refused a fix:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8248

Answer (score 0):

> Why does adding a .ghci file cause this behaviour, and what is it exactly that ghci is worried about? Without a local directory .ghci file ghci does not protest about permissions.

I guess that your `umask` is set so that all the newly created files, by default, are group writable. This allows any user in your system to write to it. Some GHCi commands allow to run any command at all. Hence, anyone who can write to your `.ghci` file will be able to essentially hijack your account as soon as you launch GHCi.

GHCi tries to prevent this attack by refusing to interpret a file which is writable by others. Whether this should be the case is arguable.

On one hand, changing the permissions is easy, and has to be done only once unless you regenerate your `.ghci`. Even if you regenerate it automatically, you can use a script which can do the `chmod` for you. Or, probably better, set your `umask` more strictly so that new files get strict permissions (I think you should use `umask 002`) -- this needs to be run once for every shell, only, or can be put in the shell init files.

On the other hand, GHCi is being a bit cautious here, unlike most of unix which uses (used?) to give you all the rope you need to hang yourself, as the saying goes. Perhaps a flag `ghci --ignore-config-permissions` would be useful.

Comment: While I think that ghc should not dictate to me how I manage the security of my personal system, I now understand that ghci can run arbitrary shell commands with the '!' command, and these could be injected into a session unknowingly if a local .ghci is included with an external downloaded package. So the design decision is trying to avoid that risk. I agree that setting a more restrictive umask is the answer, but one tends not to do this automatically on a single user workstation.